# React Native Data Binding Fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, react-native

I'm trying to build a login screen in React Native. I followed this article here: https://alitalhacoban.medium.com/basic-login-screen-with-react-native-c9f7fdcc8dae. I figure it should work but it doesn't.

Any way, here's my code:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Text  } from '../../components/Themed';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

const onPressLogin = async () => {
    var req_json = { Email: state.email, Password: state.password};

    console.log(req_json);

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": "localhost"
      }
    };

    await axios.post('http://localhost/Account/Login/', req_json, headers);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={text => setState({email: text})}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={text => setState({password: text})}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress = {onPressLogin}
        style={styles.loginBtn}>
        <Text>Log in.</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
)};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"white"
  },
  loginBtn: {

  }
});

}
```

The problem here is that the 'email' field is not being bound to the model. When you press the "Log in" button after punching in username and password... it will show the password, but the email is undefined for some reason.

This is what gets printed to the console as a result of the call back function call to the 'onPressLogin' function.

```
Object {
  "Email": undefined,
  "Password": "**********!",
}
```

It does not currently hit the ASP.NET MVC controller action for Logging in because of this.

Any ideas what's wrong with it / how to fix it??

Tried changing the server method's signature to accept a data transfer object. Still can't get the email field to bind to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the state correctly . It would be better to use separate states for email and password

```html
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity,Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {

  const [email, setemail] = useState(null)
  const [password, setpassword] = useState(null)
  

const onPressLogin = async () => {
  console.log('state',state)
    var req_json = { Email: email, Password: password};

    console.log(req_json);

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": "localhost"
      }
    };

    await axios.post('http://localhost/Account/Login/', req_json, headers);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
               onChangeText={text => setemail(text)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={text => setpassword(text)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress = {onPressLogin}
        style={styles.loginBtn}>
        <Text>Log in.</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
)};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"white"
  },
  loginBtn: {

  }
});
```

Or if you want to use single state then set the state as in below code

```html
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity,Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  })

const onPressLogin = async () => {
  console.log('state',state)
    var req_json = { Email: state.email, Password: state.password};

    console.log(req_json);

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": "localhost"
      }
    };

    await axios.post('http://localhost/Account/Login/', req_json, headers);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
                   onChangeText={text => setState({ ...state, email: text })}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
         onChangeText={text => setState({ ...state, password: text })}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress = {onPressLogin}
        style={styles.loginBtn}>
        <Text>Log in.</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
)};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"white"
  },
  loginBtn: {

  }
});
```